# Rails show error message of another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a html partial that displays errors:

shared/model_errors.html.erb

```
<% model.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
```

and I render it at top of each html file like

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/model_errors',locals: {model: @model_to_check_errors}%>
```

This is working fine for most of them.

Let's say that I'm on the `show.html.erb` template of the `ConversationsController`, and I have there a `form_tag` which submits messages to the `MessagesController`. If the submitted message is empty, the `MessagesController` won't allow it to be saved, because it has validation errors. How do I display those validations errors in my `show.html.erb`, considering I don't have access to the `@message` object of the `create` action of the `MessagesController`. Is there any way to add the error message to the `ConversationsController`? They will be displayed that way.

Edit:

show.html.erb of the `ConversationsController`

```
<div class="container nav_exp">
  <%= render partial: 'shared/model_errors',locals: {model: @???}%>
  <div class="ch-body">
    <div class="col-md-12 bg-white ">
      <div class="chat-message">
        <ul class="chat" id="messages">
          <% if @messages != nil %>
            <%= render partial: 'conv_message', collection: @messages,:as => :message%>
          <% else %>
            <div class="panel-body hidden"></div>
          <%end%>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <%=form_tag(messages_path, :method=>'post',authenticity_token: true,remote: true) do%>
        <div class="chat-box bg-white">
          <div class="input-group">
            <%= text_field_tag :body,"", id:"message_body",class: "form-control border no-shadow no-rounded", placeholder: "Type your message here"%>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :conversation_id, @conversation.id %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :receiver, @other.id %>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <%= submit_tag 'Submit', class: "btn btn-success no-rounded" %>
            </span>
          </div><!-- /input-group -->
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `create` method of the `MessagesController`  - `messages_path`

```
def create
    message = Message.new(message_params)
    message.user = current_user
    if message.save
      ...
    else
      puts 'not working'
     'I think 1 solution would be to add here flash messsages'
        end
      end

private

def message_params
  params.permit(:body, :conversation_id, :receiver)
end
```

Comment: Why would the `MessageController` need to show its errors to the `ConversationsController`? Seems like, without knowing more about your code, there is a more efficient way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Because I'm posting to it with `remote: true`, so the page won't change. Therefore the user won't be notified why the message wasn't submitted. I guess I could do something like `if @message.save .. else flash[:error] = 'problem'`.

Comment: FYI: You're using ancient syntax for rendering partials. Just use `render 'shared/modal_errors', model: @model_to_check_errors`

Comment: Even with remote, if the controller doesn't save, you can return values. You would then have to show the errors (returned by JSON) with JS

Comment: @WesFoster ok, I haven't thought about that. I will try it now.

Comment: @meagar it's not working that way. It won't pass the model.

Comment: @BogdanDaniel It absolutely will work, identically to what you have using `partial/locals`. If it's not working, it's not because of the change in syntax.

Comment: @meagar I'm not saying that I think it won't work. I tried it and it doesn't actually work. But that's not my problem here.

Comment: I updated with the view and method